# Unknown float option `0'. ... pdflatex

Tags: pdftex

I am observing an "Unknown float option `0'. .." error in the new command below.
float package is already but I am still running into problems. This code use to work fine until some time back, without the float package. But now even after including the float package it doesn't work at all.

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}    

\usepackage[left=1.27cm,right=1.27cm,top=1.02cm,bottom=1.02cm,headheight=0cm]{geometry}


\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{latexsym,siunitx}
\usepackage{titlesec,color,colortbl}
\usepackage{enumitem,soul}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
```

New command, source of error:

```
\newcommand{\cvSubheading}[4]{
    \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
    \begin{table}[0.98\textwidth]
        \sisetup{table-column-width=0}
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-text-alignment=left]S[table-text-alignment=right]SS}
            \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
            \rowcolor{Gray}
            \textit{#3} \textit{#4}\\
        \end{tabular}\vspace{-5pt}
    \end{table}
}
```

Some more errors in the new command:

```
Unknown float option `.'. ...
Unknown float option `9'. ...
Unknown float option `8'. ...
Unknown float option `\'. ...
```

Can somebody please help?

As noted in comments, the one below is the newer version, that was already with me:

```
\newcommand{\cvSubheading}[4]{
    \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
    \begin{tabular*}{.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4}\\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The width of a tabular is not an option for `table`.

Comment: @Bernard, Thanks, moving it to tabular did solve the problem.  But now I am observing another one ..Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). ...  From same new command: cvSubheading.

Comment: `tabular` doesn't accept an optional width argument either. Anyway, you *don't* need `table`. Are you sure you want `S` columns in a table meant for text?

Comment: This is embarrassing, turns out I was looking at an older version. Newer version is simpler. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you want to get? I don't understand why you'd want to use `table` after `\item`. `table` is meant for floating objects but it looks like you want to place a `tabular` at a well-defined spot, so you should drop that `table` around it.

Comment: Off-topic: It's not a good idea to load the package `color` and `colortbl` independently of each other. Instead of `\usepackage{...,color,colortbl}`, do write `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. Doing so will maximize interoperability.

Comment: And can you please post a complete example, i.e. something that compiles and shows your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The optional argument to `table` specifies float positions such as `t` for top or `h` for here, so you get an error from

```
\begin{table}[0.98\textwidth]
```

as the first character in the option is `0` which is not one of the allowed characters `!htbp`

In this case however you want the `tabular` to be in the list item, but a `table` environment marks its content as something that is not in the main document flow and can be moved, so you can simply delete the lines

```
\begin{table}[0.98\textwidth]
```

and

```
\end{table}
```

So that the `tabular` is the text of the list item started with `\item`.